# What is your strategy for adding help topics in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

How do you customize this help in CRM 2013?

[image]

It shows the following for a customized entity

[image]

It appears that the configuration of help pages in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013, On-Premise is no longer supported. In CRM 4 it [was supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150854.aspx) (Reference image 1). In CRM 2011, support [was dropped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309355.aspx) (Reference image 2) and the suggested alternative is the Getting Started pane. In CRM 2013, the Getting Started pane [was dropped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328498.aspx) from the sitemap (Reference image 3).

**Reference image 1**

[image]

**Reference image 2**

[image]

**Reference image 3**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If its no longer supported. I would add a button to ribbon and open a html webresource populated with help contents. I know used can get confused because of two buttons (custom help button and CRM help button). But with we can train users to use it custom button for help.

Some one have already requested to Microsoft for this functionality. here is the [Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/655598/integrating-or-replacing-help)

Comment: Thanks. That is a workable solution. It seems strange that MS keeps the help button around but drops support without replacing it with a different approach.

Comment: tbh, I never worked on CRM 4, I started working on CRM from version 2011. So I was not aware about this feature of CRM 4. But if it was a working/useful functionality then its strange why they removed it!

Comment: Someone have already request Microsoft for this functionality. Here is the link - https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/655598/integrating-or-replacing-help